# Continuity of covariance kernels

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, machine-learning

Let $I$ be a locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) topological space. Let $c : I \times I \to \mathbb R$ be a covariance kernel, that is, a symmetric, nonnegative-definite function.

Does it follow that $c$ must be continuous?